# imp.load_source from within package

Tags: python, import

For some Python project, I defined the default configuration in a `config` module. Customization is allowed by sourcing a rc file into it using

```
config = imp.load_source('config', 'some_rc_file')
```

The rc file might redefine only a subset of the configuration variables, or even not at all, and I expect that variables which are not redefined would still exist as attributes of the `config` module, with their default value. If `load_source` is called from `__main__`, everything goes well. However, if it is used within a package, the only variables 'left' in the module are those of the rc file.

There's a MWE [here](https://github.com/gapato/load_source_MWE). `direct.py` works as expected, but not `indirect.py`

```
.
|-- run.sh                           # runs python {,in}direct.py
|-- altconfig.py                     # the rc file, redefines (only) BAR
|-- config.py -> testimp/config.py   # symlink to use by direct.py
|-- direct.py                        # calls load_source directly
|-- indirect.py                      # calls load_source via uses_config.py
`-- testimp
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- config.py                    # default config, defines FOO and BAR
    `-- uses_config.py
```

What import logic am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `print(config)` to your test code, you'll see that the module imported by `import config` is named `config`, but the module imported by `from . import config` in testimp is called `testimp.config`.  The first argument to `load_source` is the name of the module to reuse.  Since you are looking for `config`, your existing import isn't found, and you get a new module object.

The simplest solution is to not hard code the name of the module.  Change your imp lines to this, and it will work everywhere:

```
config = imp.load_source(config.__name__, 'altconfig.py')
```